# Ansible does not run without password file

Tags: ansible

I have a very simple setup:

```
ansible-playbook -vvv playbooks/init.yml -i inventories/dev/local.hosts
ansible-playbook 2.7.8
  config file = /Users/user/code/lambda/pahan/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.7.8/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.7.2 (default, Feb 12 2019, 08:15:36) [Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]
Using /Users/user/code/lambda/pahan/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
ERROR! The vault password file /Users/user/.vault_pass.txt was not found
```

The password file is not referenced anywhere and there is no passowrd used from the vault:

ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
roles_path = ./roles

[ssh_connection]
control_path=~/%%h-%%r
pipelining = True
```

Why is it trying to access the password file anyways?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the env variable was stuck in the environment forcing ansible to read the password file.

I was able to debug this by: ansible-config -c ansible.cfg dump

```
ACTION_WARNINGS(default) = True
AGNOSTIC_BECOME_PROMPT(default) = False
ALLOW_WORLD_READABLE_TMPFILES(default) = False
ANSIBLE_COW_PATH(default) = None
ANSIBLE_COW_SELECTION(default) = default
ANSIBLE_COW_WHITELIST(default) = ['bud-frogs', 'bunny', 'cheese', 'daemon', 'default', 'dragon', 'elephant-in-snake', 'elephant', 'eyes
ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR(default) = False
ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR(default) = False
ANSIBLE_NOCOWS(default) = False
ANSIBLE_PIPELINING(/Users/user/code/lambda/pahan/ansible/ansible.cfg) = True
ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS(default) = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH(/Users/user/code/lambda/pahan/ansible/ansible.cfg) = ~/%%h-%%r
ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH_DIR(default) = ~/.ansible/cp
ANSIBLE_SSH_EXECUTABLE(default) = ssh
ANSIBLE_SSH_RETRIES(default) = 0
ANY_ERRORS_FATAL(default) = False
BECOME_ALLOW_SAME_USER(default) = False
CACHE_PLUGIN(default) = memory
CACHE_PLUGIN_CONNECTION(default) = None
CACHE_PLUGIN_PREFIX(default) = ansible_facts
CACHE_PLUGIN_TIMEOUT(default) = 86400
```

...

After removing the env variable Ansible was able to run again.